# Sort a pandas dataframe from ISO 8601 day-of-week

Tags: pandas, datetime, iso8601

I'd like to sort a Pandas dataframe by a column containing an ISO-8601 representation of the day of the week.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    { 'day': 'Mon', 'value': 13 },
    { 'day': 'Wed', 'value': 24 },
    { 'day': 'Fri', 'value': 52 },
    { 'day': 'Sun', 'value': 56 },
    { 'day': 'Sat', 'value': 42 },
    { 'day': 'Thu', 'value': 84 },
    { 'day': 'Tue', 'value': 59 }
])

df['dt_'] = pd.to_datetime(df['day'], format='%a', errors='coerce')
df = df.sort_values('dt_')

>>> print(df)
   day  value        dt_
0  Mon     13 1900-01-01
1  Wed     24 1900-01-01
2  Fri     52 1900-01-01
3  Sun     56 1900-01-01
4  Sat     42 1900-01-01
5  Thu     84 1900-01-01
6  Tue     59 1900-01-01
```

Obviously, the expected behaviour would be to have the dataframe sorted by `Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun`. According to http://strftime.org/, this `%a` format seems to be correct.

Apart from the hack that would consist in having a Dict of `day -> number`, is there any cleaner way to achieve this?

Here the example is with abbreviated day-of-week (`Dy` ISO-8601) but ideally, I'd be after a general solution to deal with any ISO-8601 input.

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest way I know how to handle this situation is to convert the `day` column to the pandas `category` data type with `ordered=True`, manually imposing the desired sort order:

```
df['day'] = pd.Categorical(df['day'], ordered=True, 
                           categories=['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu',
                                       'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'])

df = df.sort_values(by='day').reset_index(drop=True)
df
   day  value
0  Mon     13
1  Tue     59
2  Wed     24
3  Thu     84
4  Fri     52
5  Sat     42
6  Sun     56
```

The `day` column now has dtype `category` and a defined sort order:

```
df['day']
0    Mon
1    Tue
2    Wed
3    Thu
4    Fri
5    Sat
6    Sun
Name: day, dtype: category
Categories (7, object): [Mon < Tue < Wed < Thu < Fri < Sat < Sun]
```

Comment: It is better not change the original dataframe dtype

Comment: @Wen-Ben it depends on @Jivan's use case. A categorical column is more memory-efficient than leaving it as strings (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html#categorical-memory), though in this case there's likely no practical difference. Also, subsequent plots retain the `categorical` sort order, whereas with the original `object` dtype, you need to manually sort categories in plots.

Answer (score 2):

I had tried something else so just posting it:

```
import calendar
d={i[:3]:e+1 for e,i in enumerate(list(calendar.day_name))}
#{'Mon': 1, 'Tue': 2, 'Wed': 3, 'Thu': 4, 'Fri': 5, 'Sat': 6, 'Sun': 7}
df['day_num']=df.day.map(d)
df.sort_values('day_num')

   day  value        dt_  day_num
0  Mon     13 1900-01-01        1
6  Tue     59 1900-01-01        2
1  Wed     24 1900-01-01        3
5  Thu     84 1900-01-01        4
2  Fri     52 1900-01-01        5
4  Sat     42 1900-01-01        6
3  Sun     56 1900-01-01        7
```

Comment: Base on my experience , adding a help key is better than change the original dataframe dtype, nice one

Comment: @Wen-Ben Thank you. :)

Comment: Depending on OP's use case, it may be better (efficient & convenient) to convert `day` to `categorical`. For example, the days would appear in the desired order in plots if grouping by a categorical day.

Answer (score 2):

I will recommend using using `map` and `np.argsort` without change the original data type, which is more safe in real word

```
dayOfWeek={'Mon':0, 'Tue':1,'Wed':2,'Thu':3,'Fri':4,'Sat':5,'Sun':6}
df.iloc[np.argsort(df.day.map(dayOfWeek)),:]
   day  value
0  Mon     13
6  Tue     59
1  Wed     24
5  Thu     84
2  Fri     52
4  Sat     42
3  Sun     56
```